# Internet slow after reinstallation of Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: internet

I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04. Before reinstalling, the internet was fast and now internet access is very slow.

Comment: Without information about hardware specifications and how you're connecting to the internet it's impossible to have any meaningful idea.

Comment: The catalyst to re-installing was that mouning NFS share from my QNAP NAS stopped working after an Ubuntu update, and that NFS shares were more important that being in the last OS update. Anyway, I don't want that the re-instalation itself become part of the discussion.

I have no internet metrics prior to the re-installation. I think that having EXACTLY the same hardware before and after the re-installation, the hardware is not really relevant. But... Asus Z9PE-D8 WS, 2 x Xeon E5-2650, 128 GB of RAM, SATA 256 SSD. Connecting to internet using the ports integrated into the Motherboard.